# How to find and replace the text in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am a new bie to shell scripting, here i am trying to find the text and replace the text using the shell script.

what i am trying to do is, actually i have a text file which has 2 strings separated by ":
"

Like this

```
lorem:ipsum
dola:meru
etc....
```

my script will take 2 parameters while running.
now the script should check if first parameter is found or not if not found it should add it to text file.

if the first parameter is found, then it should replace the second parameter.

for example

The text file has data like this

```
lorem:ipsum
dola:meru
caby:cemu
```

i am running my script with 2 parameters like this

```
./script.sh lorem meru
```

So when i run the script it should check if the first parameter found in the file if found, the script should replace the second string..

i.e
 I ran the script like this

```
./script.sh lorem meru
```

so in the file

```
lorem:ipsum
dola:meru
caby:cemu
```

after running the script, in the line

```
lorem:ipsum
```

should get replaced to

```
lorem:meru
```

here is what i have tried..

```
#!/bin/sh
#
FILE_PATH=/home/script
FILE_NAME=$FILE_PATH/new.txt

echo $1
echo $2 
if []   then     
else 
echo $1:$2 >> $FILE_NAME
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line in your script:

```
 awk -F: -v OFS=":" -v s="$1" -v r="$2" '$1==s{$2=r}7' file > newFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` might be simpler.

```
$ cat inputfile 
lorem:ipsum
dola:meru
caby:cemu
$ pattern="lorem"
$ word="meru"
$ sed "/^$pattern:/ s/:.*/:$word/" inputfile 
lorem:meru
dola:meru
caby:cemu
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well,

input file : new.txt

```
lorem:ipsum
dola:meru
caby:cemu
```

Script file: script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/$1:.*/$1:$2/" new.txt
```

if you run the script as u wished "./script.sh lorum meru"

Output: new.txt, will be displayed as

```
lorem:meru
dola:meru
caby:cemu
```

**Explanation:**
sed is a powerful text processing tool, where u can manipulate the text as you wish with the options it provides.

**Brief explanation of the code,**
sed -i  > used to replace the contents of the original file with the new changes ( if u dont give -i in sed it will just print the modified contents without affecting the original file)

"s/old:.*/old:new/"

"s" is used for substitution. Syntax is "s/old/new/'.
Here * specifies anything that is present after the ":"
So by executing this you will get the desired output.